# Target content generated dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have 10 inputs dynamically created and i want do to a simple validation if they are not blank, the problem is that the code that i have does not work for these because they are not created at the page load.

how can i achieve this?
Thx in advance

```
function submitForm() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        if($("#input"+i).value == null){
            alert("False!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put this code in $(document).ready()?

Comment: I would use a jquery .each to solve this, have you tried that?

Comment: If the $(document).ready() not work can you explain when the input was created?

Comment: the $(document).ready() did not work, the inputs are being create at a click of a button, in another function.

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/394/?

Comment: `$("#input"+i).value` will not work with anything, dynamic or not because jQuery objects to not have a `value` property. Instead you should use `$("#input"+i).val()`.

Comment: Thx Nenad Vrakar it worked like a charm!!!

Comment: How do i select your comment as correct answer?

Comment: @Carolina Vicente i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `val()` to check input value instead of `value`

```js
(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('body').append('<input type="text" id="input-' + i + '">');
    i++;
  });

  $('input[type="submit"]').click( function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        alert($(this).attr('id') + ' is empty');
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<button>Create input</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.val()` instead of `.value`. I also suggest using `.each()`. Also when `input` is empty, its value is `""` not `null`.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    if($("#input"+i).val() == "") {
        alert($("#input"+i).attr('id') + " is empty!")
    }
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somrlik/u4b76L34/)